Superset stored procedure runs in sql lab but not in chart
I have Superset 3.1.3. I have a connection with Sql Server through ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. I have enabled the dml option to run stored procedures.
The SP runs in the Sql Lab. But when I choose CREATE CHART then the SP doesn't run and in the place of chart appears:
Error: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXECUTE'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Also it doesn't allow me to save it as dataset. It throws Fatal Error!
I don't understand why?
the SP is : EXEC testSP 2 (the parameter 2 is for test and I have tested it with '2' also)
This happens only for SPs
